# The convergence of a bounded sequence with a specific property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

I tried to show that the series associated with this sequence to converge and tried many other things like Ratio test but none of this worked...
It would be a big help if anyone gives me a hint.

Comment: The series with $a_{k+1}-a_k$ converges if and only if $(a_n)$ converges.

Comment: Put $b_k = a_{k} - a_{k-1}$. The given inequality directly implies that $b_n$ is increasing. Moreover, as $(a_n)$ is bounded, so is $(b_n)$. Therefore, $(b_n)$ converges.

Comment: Your argument tells me that this sequence converges by Monotone convergence Theorem which makes sense ... but I still do not see how b_n goes to 0

Answer (score 0):

Say, $a_{k+1} > a_k$ for some $k$ and $d := a_{k+1}-a_k$. Then $a_{k+2}$ has at least to be $a_{k+1} + d$. And then $a_{k+3}$ has at least to be $2a_{k+2} - a_{k+1} \ge a_{k+2}+ d\ge a_{k+1}+2d$ and so on. This isn't bounded. Therefore, $a_n$ has to be decreasing. As $a_n$ is bounded, $a_n$ converges to some $a$. Hence, $a_{k+1} - a_k$ tends to $a-a = 0$.